# Kubernetes - Running the CI/CD pipeline on the prod cluster

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

First of all, a disclaimer - I know that this questions might be too "open-ended" for SO, but I honestly could not find a better place for it (and the [K8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/troubleshooting/) specifically recommend any questions be directed to SO).

My company has decided to switch the main production infrastructure to Kubernetes. However, there is some significant pushback from the developers, who would prefer *not* to run the CI/CD pipeline on the same cluster as the production workloads. They prefer to keep some dedicated VMs for that purpose, the main reason given that "we should not put all our eggs in one basket".

With me coming from the other side of devops (the "ops" side), I would prefer to have everything in one place, managed using the same set of tools. Unfortunately, I cannot find any documented best practices stating one way or another.

So my questions are:

1. Based on personal experience, would you recommend one type of deployment over another? Why?
2. Can anyone point me to a link making the argument one way or another? Any recommendations that we should follow in such a case?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the Kubernetes website gives vague/bad advice re: coming to Stack Overflow; I've filed a request with the company to reach out to K8s and have them update that page to specify only ask on-topic, programming questions. That aside, if you have such a strong feeling about your question being off-topic on SO, the right next step is definitely not "ask anyway". Regarding better places, off the top of my head, the *Kubernetes site's own discussion forum* would be a better place. Also, https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/ would work.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, I cannot find any documented best practices stating one way or another.

This is all depends on how strong separation you want. In Kubernetes you *can* separate environments by using a separate `namespace`, but for professional company environments, you typically want stronger separation. If you use a cloud provider, it is common to separate with a different account for "production", aslo with different access rights.

> developers, who would prefer not to run the CI/CD pipeline on the same cluster as the production workloads.

If this is for a professional organization, I agree with them. You want to use completely separated VMs, network and load balancer. If you use a cloud provider, it is also good to use a different *cloud account* and *vpc* (virtual private cloud - network).

### Recommendation

> With me coming from the other side of devops (the "ops" side), I would prefer to have everything in one place, managed using the same set of tools.

I agree with both *you* and *your developers*. Use a dedicated cluster for production and a different cluster for development. Do all changes in the production cluster via CI/CD pipelines. Restrict access (at least, write access) to the production environment.

With that setup, you only have **two** clusters that are in active use, not more - but also strong separation for the production environment.

### References

See [Best practices for enterprise organizations](https://cloud.google.com/docs/enterprise/best-practices-for-enterprise-organizations) for a good document on best practices for organizations.